# Relating noise spectral densities of magnetic flux and voltage

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity, maxwell-equations, noise

My problem is as follows. I generate a voltage $V$. This voltage is applied to a resistor R, producing a current $I$. This current is then passed through a superconducting coil, producing a magnetic flux $\Phi$. Now, this should all be nicely linearly related. I'd say $U = RI$ would suffice, and for the flux, $B = \mu_0 N I / H$ where $N$ is the winding number and $H$ the length of the solenoid. The flux is then $\Phi = B\cdot A = B A cos \theta$ with $A$ the area over which we consider the flux.

My question then follows from the following considerations. The voltage I am applying is not constant in time, it has some noise component with a spectral density $S_{VV}(f)$; say that I do some spectroscopy on my voltage source and that I know this spectrum. The resistor of course also produces some thermal noise with a certain spectrum $S_{RR}(f)$. I'll assume that the area $A$, winding number $N$ and length $H$ are constant. How would I then relate the final noise spectral density of the flux $S_{\Phi\Phi}(f)$ to my initial $S_{VV}(f)$?